# Centering a div within another div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to center the navigation within the main content div and have it stuck there while scrolling. The problem that I just can't wrap my head around is that it needs to be parallaxy because of the header and the footer. I have a staging environment http://stage.golishlaw.com/portfolio/

I cannot write down everything that I have tried but some of the most recent stuff is:

```
var _mainHeight = (($(window).height()/2) - ($("#portfolio_nav").height()/2)) + (($("#main").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()))
$("#portfolio_nav").css({
    top: _mainHeight
});
```

This one worked well on some monitor sizes but not others.

```
var mainScrollTop = (($(window).scrollTop() - $("#main").offset().top));
mainScrollTop = mainScrollTop > 0 ? 0 : mainScrollTop;
var _mainHeight =  ((($(window).height() )/2 - $("#portfolio_nav").height()/2) + $("#main").offset().top) + mainScrollTop
$("#portfolio_nav").css({
    top: _mainHeight
});
```

This one work pretty well to but the nav got stuck at a certain spot (I know why I just can't figure how to get it stuck in the center of the screen)

I've just really been pulling my hair out on this one and I've tried everything that I could think of.

Comment: I don't really get it, you want it centered vertically and static in the outer div right? No need to bind scroll handlers nor use jQuery for this.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to do this without jQuery. I cannot use fixed position because fixed is on the browser and I need it centered within a div within the browser

Comment: @locrizak I posted one without jQuery

Comment: I revised mine to work with a header and footer - no jquery needed.

Comment: @Cynthia Did you even see the crazy reqs OP commented in the other answers? He won't accept `fixed` position and he wants some kind of proportionally reducing an initial offset while you scroll because there could be a larger header and he wants the nav to stay inside the container.

Comment: the header can be any size he wants it to be. The end result is that the nav stays inside the container, centered horizontally and vertically. His not wanting to used 'fixed' wasn't because he had an issue w/ it per se but because he didn't think it would work.

Comment: I see, I'll give you the credit for apparently understanding his request. Best of luck for the OP and your answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer as well with my interpretation of OP's request, because I don't leave an answer unfinished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already defining the left position with CSS: `absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -401px;` So add this CSS to your `#portfolio_nav` rule to center it vertically:

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -80px;
```

Make sure to comment out the jQuery code which sets the top CSS property otherwise it will override the CSS rule.

**margin-top calc**: Each list item has around `40px` (`height + padding-bottom`) so 4 `li` * 40 = 160 / 2 = -80px `margin-top`. Or just subtract 20px each time you add a list item. Of course, this calc can be done through jQuery setting the `marginTop` later if you need to add list items dynamically.

If you want an even more accurate vertical center, you can do the maths not accounting for the `padding-bottom` of the last list item as its padding-bottom is not visible. `margin-top:-70px` is slightly more centered.

---

**Update** to center it vertically in the browser window while respecting the container restriction:

```
$(function() {
    var $pnav = $('#portfolio_nav'),
        $w = $(window);
    $pnav.css('top', 0);
    $w.scroll(function() {
        var $p = $pnav.parent(),
            pptop = parseInt($p.css('paddingTop'), 10),
            ppbottom = parseInt($p.css('paddingBottom'), 10),
            pheight = $p.height(),
            pnavheight = $pnav.height();
        $pnav.css('top', $w.height()/2 - ($p.offset().top + pptop) - pnavheight/2 + $w.scrollTop());

        var pnavpostop = $pnav.position().top;
        if (pnavpostop < pptop) $pnav.css('top', pptop);
        else if (pnavpostop + pnavheight > pptop + pheight + ppbottom) $pnav.css('top', pheight - pnavheight);
    }).scroll();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/GdQvw/4/)

Comment: This will NOT work. This will work if the whole container fits on the page which I am doing if that is the case. My problem is when the content area is larger than the page (when there is a scroll bar) Yes this will be centered vertically in the div but it will not be centered on the screen

Comment: @locrizak Yes, I made it to center in the div. So, you want it centered in the div when there is no scrollbar and centered in the window when there is? Your question says: `I am trying to center the navigation within the main content div and have it stuck there while scrolling.` by "stuck while scrolling" I assumed it wasn't supposed to move at all. Could you add the exact expected behavior on your question?

Comment: @locrizak You can't have it centered in the container AND in the window all the time. If you want it centered in the window, use `fixed` instead of `absolute` position. If you want centered in the div, keep the `absolute` pos. If it's something else, please elaborate.

Comment: @locrizak updated answer with jQuery code.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you can't have it centered int he container and the window at all time considering I said I almost got it to do just that. Thanks for the example but its not the effect I am looking for. I want it to be centered all the time, not fixed to the top and bottom when the whole container isn't on screen

Comment: @locrizak sorry but this is purely logic. Center is relational. Center of one thing !== center of another thing unless both are centered in the same axis - also the window center changes when you scroll so to have both centered the container must be fully visible and centered. Otherwise I fail to see what want. Maybe you want the center of the visible area of the container? Then it won't be the center of the screen.

Comment: I never said it needed to be centered in the screen. It needs to be centered in the #main div. I'm sorry I couldn't explain it better but take a look at it now, centered within the div while scrolling. You also don't need that much code to accomplish what you had provided. I did the same things in 4 lines without any if statements. Thanks again for trying to help out.

Comment: This somewhat lead me to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create your own body DIV with overflow: scroll. Append it to the body. Then you can add a second div to the body which is your center div. This div has an absolute position and is centered on the screen. Then you put the whole content of the page into your own body DIV. So when you scroll, it feels like you scroll the body, but actually you are scrolling the body DIV.

Comment: I'd rather not have a scroll bar on div.

Answer (score 0):

Change these 2 on your page

```
 #portfolio_nav {
 width: 200px;
 top: 300px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -401px;
 position: fixed;                 /*this line*/
 }


 .page-template-portfolio-php #contentblock_tile, .contentcontainer_tile {
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  position: absolute;             /* this line */
  }
```

Comment: Why dont you center vertically ,the same way you centered horizontally. Check @FabricoMatte answer

Comment: yea you , could do that , I was just showing position fixed inside position absolute will make the menu stay there ,  you can mess with the actual spot it's in

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but when adding your rules to Chrome Dev Tools, the `position:fixed` still scrolls with the browser window.

Comment: Well, you can read in the question's comments, OP wants it centered in the div and not the browser window. `=]`

Comment: Depending on window resolution, OP's jQuery scroll handler messes up the positioning.

Comment: I CANNOT use position:fixed. This is not fixed within the div as it is fixed within the browser. I need it to be fixed within the content area as the page is scrolled. So when the header is on the screen there will be a top offset. When the page is scrolled that offset slowly go down to 0 and I will be just centering the nav on the page

Comment: @locrizak Add that behavior to the question then. You're just complicating simple things IMO but I'll take a look.